# Why is order of message in pseudo channel "threads" different?

Tags: slack

In direct messages or normal channels the new messages are at the bottom (like in WhatsApp).

But in the pseudo channel "threads" it is different. There the messages are at the top.

[image: slack--sorting-of-channel-threads]

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: "Is there a good reason for this?" is an off-topic question for this site (and having two question on a post makes it too broad). Please add more details and context to make it possible to provide a helpful answer. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The sort order in Slack is not configurable.

Normal channels display new messages at the bottom to follow the same format as traditional text message and chat platforms.

The **Threads** tab displays all of your sub-level conversations in one place. The threads with the most recent updates are displayed at the top of the window to draw the user's attention right away.

Comment: I just tried Pebbles and it doesn't actually sort threads or messages or anything. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah, with the speed of Slack's development, I doubt any third-party tools will be reliable. Good news is that Slack is now letting you group channels into different sections.

Comment: It has nothing to do with reliability. The app you linked to doesn't purport to actually rearrange anything. That's just not what it's designed to do. It's just a Slack app that does ordinary Slack app things. To affect the UI in the way we're looking for, we'd need more than a Slack app, we'd need something like a "Slack extension" and there's no such thing.

Comment: Good call, I have removed the link from my answer.